# Server Timeout after most recent Windows Update

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, windows-update

I have a couple of classic asp pages that hit an Access database (as well as an Excel table) that are suddenly no longer working after the most recent Windows update earlier this week.

I'm now getting an error

> Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0113' Script timed out

and I'm getting back two or three rows of data in 30 minutes, where I used to get 300+ in a couple of minutes.

Does anyone have any thoughts about what might be causing this problem? No code has changed, and I'm at a loss. (I have IIS and the database running on my local machine.)

I've found some articles from a few years ago where an update to Windows caused some issues for Classic ASP (the solution was to uninstall one of the updates), but I've seen nothing from the most recent update. Any thoughts are much appreciated.

ETA: Just rolled back my Windows update to the previous version and everything's back to normal. Not sure how to proceed. Am I stuck on this build forever?

Comment: Could you post any more of the error?  The exact stack trace or print out of the error would be a helpful start.

Comment: Ensure the security zone context for which you are executing any VBScript /VBA code is located in either the **Local Computer**, **Local intranet**, or **Trusted Sites** zone.

Any content now deemed in the **Internet** or **Restricted Sites** zones will most likely not run VBScript/VBA any longer, due to recent Microsoft security updates.

You may be seeing a side-effect of these recent Windows security updates.  Note: There are registry settings and group policy settings to allow users to continue running VBScript/VBA in risky security zone contexts, if absolutely necessary.

Comment: Most likely changes to security context which we see often with new versions of server and security updates. Follow advice of @leeharvey1